# is this sample sql statement considered parameterized and therefore safe?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, prepared-statement

```
$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO whatever (col1,col2) values (%d,%s)",$_GET['unescaped_and_unfiltered_col1_value'],$_GET['unescaped_and_unfiltered_col2_value']);
```

How is the above method any different than using the bindParam or the bindValue methods as far as SQL-Injection escaping is concerned?

Comment: -1 and voting to close. This is Q&A site, not site to play riddles.

Comment: @col. shrapnel i don't see why you interpreted it that way. no doubt you misunderstood  the intent here but still, can't figure it out what made you think that way... with this question, I was seeking to to find out if the %d or %s mapping is as safe as ? or the named placeholder mapping alternatives that are used in PDO. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nobody in the whole world can tell you if it's safe or not. Just because no one have an idea what $dbh->prepare is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are going to just mimic this behavior, using some symbols like %d,$s to represent your data, *without implementing some underlying technique*, it is apparently NOT safe. %d and $s symbols have no magic meaning makes whatever data whatever safe.

If you are going to use some *library* you come across, and want to ask, if this library safe or not, you have to at least **name** it, but better present **technology** it is using to let people have an idea of what you're asking for.

Okay, it's all about symbols.
Like I said above, either if you meant `%s`, not `$s`, these are just are printf() function placeholders and has nothing to do with security nor with databases at all.

However, you still can create a system of safety implementing such placeholders, which of course, have to escape|bind these parameters in it's underlying level.

a quick example of such a function:

```
function prepare() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $query = array_shift($args);
  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  }
  return vsprintf($query, $args);
}
```

by using it this way

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO whatever (col1,col2) values (%d,'%s')",
                     $_GET['unescaped_and_unfiltered_col1_value'],
                     $_GET['unescaped_and_unfiltered_col2_value']);
```

you can be sure you made your data values safe. Yet identifiers and keywords steel needs protection.

Hope I got all things sorted out.

Comment: Thanks Col Shrapnel...  Since so many people have honestly tried but not able to understand the question, I take the question back. I should have named/coined the darn question in a different way. People all just got stuck in the technology, what really that 4dbh, or PDO or nonPDO stuff is... Let's scrape that all out, cause that part is irrelavant. And btw, there is no library I'm investigating, there is no such code neither. I was trying to find out by simply using the %d ( for digit ) and the %s for (string), are we effectively doing the same thing as we do with named place holders; TBC...

Comment: continuing... With named place holders, (:first_name) for example, you provide its value by binding it by bindParam. This way, we can fearlessly not escape that value. Cause the underlying DB engine knows that it is a userstring and it cannot be executed as code... Now back to my little %d and %s. Is same thing happening here? When using the %s for example, do I need to escape its corresponding variable so can I just pass its value without worrying just like in the :first_name place holder example? So when we do INSERT INTO whatever (col1) values ($s)",$the_var], should the_var be escaped?

Comment: I can but only cite myself: `%d and $s symbols have no magic meaning makes whatever data whatever safe.` See extended answer for the details.

Comment: good catch... i had meant %s not $s. Yes, I was referring to the printf function place holders... so %s stands for string... so this sentence of yours "%s, this is just a printf() function placeholder and has nothing to do with security nor with databases at all. " does it! The question is answered. I'm sorry for making it more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PDO. It is wrong.

Take a look at the [PDO manual](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Your code would be

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO whatever (col1,col2) values (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['key1'], $_GET['key2']));
```

The values would be escaped and secure to use.

Comment: The code was inspired from the wordpres codex right from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). 
it's under the section titled *Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks* here is an excerpt;
  
    $metakey = "Harriet's Adages";
    
    $metavalue = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
    ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
    10, 
    $metakey, 
    $metavalue 
    ) );
    
I don't see why you said it's wrong.

Comment: You didn't say you are using wordpress, so I guessed you are using standard PDO. Wordpress has their own SQL wrapper. So if you are working with wordpress your code would be fine and should be escaped correctly.

Comment: well remy, yes, that's wp but i don't really care. i just happened to grab the code from there. the point in the question was ( which was obviously not well formed and that's my bad ) was this; when we do %s, does that %s has the same quality of escaping power as a :first_name being binded with $first_name? see what I'm asking? In PDO with prepared statements when you bind $first_name like that, it does not matter how malicious the value of the first_name is. The code and the user string perfectly isolated. Does the same kind of isolation exist when we used the code I included in the question?

Comment: @JohnSmith: This has nothing to do with the code you posted (how the methods are called), but how the methods are implemented. And since you and nobody mentioned it was a wordpress method, @remy just assumed it was a standard PDO call. You cannot use `?` in wordpress queries and you cannot use `%s` in standard PDO queries, the two are independent implementations

Comment: allright, let me rephrase it then.. Is this statement safe? $nonePDO->prepare("INSERT INTO whatever (col1) values ($s)",$_GET['unescaped_and_unfiltered_col1_value']);     Is it as safe as $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO whatever (col1) values (:col1)");$pdo->bindParam(":col1",$col1_val);pdo->execute();

Comment: @JohnSmith: How should we know?? That solely depends on how NonePDO::prepare() is implemented. Either look at its source or trust the documentation's/author's claims about security.

Comment: @Knitti: I was simply looking for an apple to apple comparison. But the question was not understood well. Let's forget it guys, I'll figure it out later.

Comment: @JohnSmith "not understood well", my foot. It was ASKED wrong way. There is NO APPLE to compare in your question, can't you understand that? You just throw in a piece of code which noone in the world have an idea of, and ask to compare it!